# Copy/merge data from 2 workbooks to one master workbook

Tags: vba, excel, loops, commandbutton

I have 2 spreadsheets that are identical being filled out by different people. I tried to then get their separate data to copy into a mater spreadsheet that is the same as the first but hopefully with the 2 sets of data combined. 
I've managed to set up a command button "submit" into my sheet that will copy rows from one spreadsheet but when the other person presses "submit" it just overrides the others data...
I know I need to write a loop and if but I can't get it work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("X:\TA Info\MASTER.xlsx")
Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

sht1.Cells.Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkb2.Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I understand this is a very unique question but I will appreciate any guidance anyone has the time to offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
 sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Always pastes into range A1, overwriting anything there. To append the data below existing data use

```
  sht2.Range("A" & sht2.rows.count).End(xlup).offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Ahh - but you can't copy all the cells in a sheet except into A1 - so we need to only copy the used cells. Changing

```
  sht1.Cells.Copy
```

into

```
  sht1.UsedRange.Cells.Copy
```

Comment: I altered very slightly 'sht2.Range("A2" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues' still getting 1004 error "Method 'Range' of object_'worksheet' failed"

Comment: No that won't work. What we are doing is starting at the very bottom of the spreadsheet (at row 1million) with range("A" & total number of row) and then we come up to the first occupied cell with .end(xlup) and then down 1 row with .offset(1,0)

Adding a random A2 makes no sense.  You need to replace your line with the one I gave

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but it's kicking back an error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" and I can't figure out why or how to fix it..?!

Comment: I think this should work but now im getting an error saying there isnt enough memory????!! and then an error that says "pastespecial method of range class failed"....i'm just about ready to give up now and am completely grateful for your patience!!!